# unity (Android bild), i have problem "We can't assign a new GUID because the asset is in an immutable folder. The asset will be ignored."

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, guid

I have unity 2019.3.7f1,
2 sided libraries:

```
GooglePlayGamesPlugin-0.10.08
GoogleMobileAds-v3.18.3
```

(it also installed "latest External Dependency Manager for Unity")

And everything compiled perfectly on Android (apk)

I added a library `Firebase 6.13.0` and got the following errors:
[image: Err]
I read that you need to delete them and restart the project, it did not help, I also reinstalled all the libraries, it did not help.

Has anyone had similar problems? Please help solve it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It **helped** me:

- Update Unity to 2019.4.15f
- Update Firebase to 6.16.1
- Update GooglePlayGamesPlugin-0.10.11
- Update GoogleMobileAds-v5.4.0 (optional)
- **Remove** *Assets/ExternalDependencyManager* and *Assets/PlayServicesResolver* folder

Answer (score 2):

According to this thread: https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-unity/issues/695

> It looks like EDM4U is installed from both UPM and in Assets folder.
>
> If you install any Firebase packages from UPM, EDM4U will be
> automatically installed through UPM as well, as a dependency. That is
> why we recommend to remove EDM4U from Assets folder BEFORE installing
> any Firebase SDK from UPM.
>
> This may happen when you install any other packages including EDM4U or
> PlayServicesResolver in their .unitypackage, ex. Facebook, OneSignal.
> All you need is to remove those folders
> (`Assets/ExternalDependencyManager` and/or
> `Assets/PlayServicesResolver`) from `Assets` folder. Unfortunately
> EDM4U cannot resolve such installation conflict now but we are looking
> for some solution to make your life easier.
>
> To resolve this, I recommend you to:
>
> Remove `Assets/ExternalDependencyManager` and/or
> `Assets/PlayServicesResolver` folder
>
> 1. Uninstall all Firebase packages from UPM
> 2. Reinstall all needed
>    Firebase packages from UPM (this guarantees assets ignored by Unity
>    during previous installation is installed properly this time)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have two of the same dll files conflicting with each other one here:

```
Assets/ExternalDependencyMAnager/Editor/Google.iOSResolver_v1.2.144.dll
```

and one in

```
Packages/com.google.external-dependency-manager/ExternalDependencyManager/Editor/Google.iOSResolver_v1.2.144.dll
```

Try deleting (cut and paste to a diff directory to do it safely) the 
Assets/ExternalDependencyManager/Editor/Google.iOSResolver_v1.2.144.dll

Unity is also telling you its in an immutable folder so it may not have permissions to access it itself

Answer (score 0):

Installing Unity Ads
To ensure the latest version of Unity Ads, download it through the Asset store, or through the Unity Package Manager in the Editor.

Important: You must choose either the Asset or the package. Installing both may lead to build errors.
[source](https://unityads.unity3d.com/help/unity/integration-guide-unity#basic-implementation)

Comment: I need Google Admob, Unity Ads supports Admob?

Comment: Unity supports Admob. So you can use Admob in Unity. However Unity Ads and Admob are monetization platform : Unity Ads is just a monetization platform/thing like Admob

Answer (score 0):

from unity editor
1.windows
2.package manager
3.In Project
and Remove External dependencies folder or package.[you can see package manager is open with In Project selected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TbdCV.png)

Answer (score 0):

In Unity 2020.3.11f1 LTS version: Just restart the Unity. The problem fixed for me.